# T-SQL Query Many to Many

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables:

```
doctors:
-----------
id
name

language:
-----------
id
name

languageDoctors:
----------------
doctor_id
language_id
```

I would like to return a JSON with the doctor name and after it an array of the  languages that the doctor has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use `for json path` to construct the json:

```
select d.*,
       (select l.name as language
        from doctor_languages dl join
             languages l
             on dl.language_id = l.language_id
        where dl.doctor_id = d.doctor_id
        for json path
       ) as languages
from doctors d;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a9badcdb7620e50784298fd3d9b0cb36) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: can you explain what you did in this query? im new to sql and i dont know what 'with' is

Comment: @צחחורי . . . Those introduce *common table expressions* (CTEs).  You can think of them as convenient ways to define subqueries.